# How to convert a Web App into a Native Chrome Application

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Often I search the chrome web store and find applications that are just a link to the actual web page. To me this is a complete waste of time as I like the ability to just work with the page or app directly on the desktop.

My question is , in the recent months, i'm starting to see more and more Web Apps being packaged to the chrome webstore as Native Chrome Apps. How is this done, I asked one author and their response was "It's very easy to do". And that's all I have heard.

I am very curious about this, and would be happy to accept any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML5 features to create application that run without connection to the internet, they can even store data in a local storage.

I bet it is easy to find more details about this by yahooing that topic ;-)

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It absolutely amazes me how people will just downvote a post just to get points for their rating. It should be a requirement that you provide an answer, or that you provide a reason behind why you are downvoting a post. This question has been up for literally 10 minutes and already there are downvotes.

Comment: I assume it's the same [beeep] that downvoted my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the way to go.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-sign-builder/odjaaghiehpobimgdjjfofmablbaleem?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon